# Oracle: How to convert row count into data size

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to know how do i convert number of row into size like in MB or KB?
Is there a way to do that or formula?

The reason I doing this is because I would like to know given this set of data but not all in tablespace, how much size is used by this set of data.

Thanks,
keith

Answer (score 1):

If you want an estimate, you could multiple the row count with the information from [`user_table.avg_row_len`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D.htm#REFRN20286) for that table.

If you want the real size of the table *on disk*, this is available [`user_segments.bytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-35B6E56B-FF96-4F39-9BF7-F8E185935CAA.htm#REFRN26243). Note that the smallest unit Oracle will use is a block. So even for an empty table, you will see a value that is bigger tzen zero in that column. That is actual size of the space reserved in the tablespace for that table.